# Laravel custom error page if authorization fails

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show a custom 403 file in laravel when authorization fails in my edit request.

I tried `forbiddenResponse()` but as it turns out it has been eliminated.

Then I tried `failedauthorization()` but this does not redirect as well and allows me to edit.

here is my request file

```
public function authorize()
{
  $job_posting_id = $this->route('id');

  $job_posting = Job_postings::where('id', $job_posting_id)->where('user_id', user()->id)->exists();

  if($job_posting){
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

public function failedAuthorization()
{

  return redirect('errors.dashboard.parent.403');
}
```

I have a folder called errors and inside there I have dashboard folder and parent where the error file is located.

How can I redirect to that page if authorization fails?

Comment: `return view('errors.dashboard.parent.403')`?

Comment: I tried that as well, but it just keeps passing it and goes to editing.

Comment: You need to create an exception and in Exceptions/Handler.php file's report method do `if($e instance of YOUREXCEPTION){ // here return your view }`

Comment: @Vikash can you write an answer how I can do it? I tired to write the method if handler.php?

Comment: Do you want for any 403 code ?

Comment: @Vikash yes please

Comment: I have written the answer, please check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return abort('403')
```

Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#http-exceptions

---

if you make everything like in docs, you'll achieve:

1. url will stay the same.
2. template `resources/views/errors/403.blade.php` will be shown.
3. aslo response will have Status Code:403 Forbidden

do you want change url into http://www.examlpe.com/error403 ?

return abort('403') doesn't make redirect. It just shows a client that error has occured.

---

In your case it is easier to show different content in single script, than different scripts. Try to leave single error script as an "entry point". And in that script change output for different users. Imagine that 403.blade.php is a layout for a number of 403 error pages.

Comment: this does not help me anyway nor answers the question. I have read the documentation.

Comment: why am I trying to do this is that I have two error pages, one for not logged in users and other is for logged in users, one file is located in errors/ and the other one is in errors/dashboard. How can I show the different error page?

Answer (score 2):

In your laravel folder open app/Exceptions/Handler.php paste the following code. That will return custom error page for 403 and 500 error.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom_all', [], 500);
    }

    if ($exception instanceof \Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 403);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Your answer implicit assumes that the OP uses the Spatie Permission package, which is not mentioned anywhere in the question.

Please don't post code and *tell* it will work, explain what the code does and *why* it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function authorize()
{
  $job_posting_id = $this->route('id');

  $job_posting = Job_postings::where('id', $job_posting_id)->where('user_id', user()->id)->exists();

  if($job_posting){
    return true;
  }

  return redirect('/error');
}

public function failedAuthorization()
{

  return view('errors.dashboard.parent.403');
}
```

In your route

```
Route::get('error', 'YourController@failedAuthorization');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file **Exceptions/Handler.php's** `report` method.

```
 public function report(Exception $e)
 {
     if(!Auth::check())
     {
        // Do whatever you want - redirect or return something
     }
     if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 403)
     {
         // Do whatever you want - redirect or return something
     }
    return parent::report($e);
 }
```

And wherever your authorisation failed, just write `abort(403)`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Vikash, why am I trying to do this is that I have two error pages, one for not logged in users and other is for logged in users. How can I show the different error page? also your answer does not redirect to the page

Comment: Check once, if it helps